LazyVim. Telescope file search doesn’t work in git repositories
I’ve started using LazyVim and I’m encountering an error when trying to find files in a folder with a .git directory using key bindings <leader>ff, <leader>fF, <leader>gf. However, everything works fine in ordinary folders without a .git directory. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?
OS Windows11
NVIM v0.9.5
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.1703942320
telescope.nvim
branch master
commit 2d0d057
E5108: Error executing lua: ...data/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:448: D:\TestRepo is not a git directory
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...data/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:448: in function 'try_worktrees'
    ...data/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:481: in function 'set_opts_cwd'
    ...data/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/__git.lua:497: in function 'v'
    ...-data/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/init.lua:580: in function <...-data/lazy/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/builtin/init.lua:539>
    ...al/nvim-data/lazy/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/util/telescope.lua:55: in function <...al/nvim-data/lazy/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/util/telescope.lua:20>

tried to disable try_worktree function, ff works, but returns an empty list of files

This might be releated to ownership which can be confirmed by running git status. If so, you can run git config --global --add safe.directory * to disable for all projects or git config --global --add safe.directory path for certain project.

ty, it worked! with warning, but anyway)
